# Dreamweaver DOM getCurrentLine()

Tags: api, dom, dreamweaver

I'm currently trying to create a small panel extension that recreates the 'minimap' feature on the Sublime Text 2 code editor, but for Dreamweaver. I've successfully created the view but I want to click anywhere in the minimap and the current page will scroll down to the current line that was clicked. 
Unfortunately, I can only find the 'getCurrentLines()' code function for the Dreamweaver DOM that returns character offsets rather that line numbers. Does anyone know how I can return the current line number from the document?

I can scroll down the user document by hard-coding a value in using the theDOM.source.setCurrentLine(200); code, but it's getting that number which is stumping me! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd be interested in testing this panel out: danilo [at] shimmerphase [dot] com

Comment: I've sent you a copy of the install MXP file. See what you think! (My email is andy.n.p [at] gmail [dot] com

Comment: I've finished the code and project and you can download for free here: [MiniMap Panel](http://albionartworks.com/?portfolio=dreamweaver-cs5-minimap-panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is dom.getLineFromOffset() can take one of the offsets and find the associated line, however, that should work only in the document window, not sure if that will assist in taking a selection in this "view" (by which I assume you mean panel) to move that into the document being edited.

Comment: Thanks Danilo. I managed to use the document.selection(); function from the panels' textarea and plug it into the dom.getLineFromOffset() function that you mentioned. This then returned the top/bottom line numbers. All seems to be working now.